# How can I create a dummy model in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using keras and trying to train a classifier on 64x64 images.

I am trying to optimise my training pipeline and to catch the bottlenecks.

To this end I'm trying to create the simpler Keras model so that I know what time the whole process (loading image, data augmentation,...) takes with a very low charge on the GPU.

So far I managed to write:

```
def create_network_dummy():
  INPUT_SHAPE = (64, 64, 1)
  inputs = Input(INPUT_SHAPE)
  out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (1,1), strides=(64,64), 1)(inputs)
  model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[out])
  return model
```

Is it possible to have an even smaller one ? Returning a constant won't do because it breaks the graph and keras will not allow it.

Answer (score 2):

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda
from keras.models import Model

inp = Input((64,64,1))
out = Lambda(lambda x: K.identity(x))(inp)
model = Model(inp,out) #You could even try Model(inp,inp)
```

??

If the idea is to have a model that does nothing, this seems the best.
You can return a constant too, you don't really need to "train" to see what you proposed, you can just "predict".

```
model.predict_generator(....)
```

---

## Another model wich outputs 1 class

```
inp = Input((64,64,1))
out = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,0,0])(inp)
model = Model(inp,out)
```

Comment: I want it to be tested in my training pipeline. So I need my output not to be the same size as my input but only 1 value (class).

Comment: @Scratch, see in the answer.

Comment: nice I did not think about taking the first value. That works!

Comment: `NameError: name 'Input' is not defined`

Comment: @techkuz, follow keras basic tutorials to know what to import. `from keras.layers import Input`.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no need to even use `K.identity`:

```
inp = Input((64, 64, 1))
out = Lambda(lambda x: x)(inp)
model = Model(inp, out)
```

Comment: It's probably even possible to do `Model(inp,inp)`, but I believe some warnings will appear.

Comment: @DanielMöller No, it is not. Input layer is a placeholder and therefore it cannot both be fed and fetched.

Comment: I want it to be tested in my training pipeline. So I need my output not to be the same size as my input but only 1 value (class).